# Firebase reactjs is not returning docs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
var db=firebase.firestore()
db.collection('sp')
.get()
.then(snapshot=>{
  console.log(snapshot)
})
.catch(err=>console.log(err))
```

This code is supposed to return the docs as objects but its returning weird stuff.

[image: The result on console]

Answer (score 1):

The `snapshot` you get in your `then` method is a `QuerySnapshot`. To inspect its contents, you should use the methods and properties defined for it.

For example, from the documentation on [getting data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#web_4) contains this example:

> ```
> db.collection("cities").where("capital", "==", true)
>     .get()
>     .then(function(querySnapshot) {
>         querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
>             // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
>             console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
>         });
>     })
>     .catch(function(error) {
>         console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
>     })
> ```

If we apply this to your code, it'd become:

```
var db=firebase.firestore()
db.collection('sp')
.get()
.then(snapshot=>{
    snapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
        // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
        console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
    });
})
.catch(err=>console.log(err))
```